# Null field, but not null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So I've got the following lines of code:

```
else
            {
                //if not found, call Gateway Add()
                user.Id = await C3SDbContext.UserGateway.NextIdAsync(context);

                user.CreatedById = modifier.CreatedById;
                user.CreatedBy = modifier.CreatedBy;
                user.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                user.UserType = "G";
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.UserType);
                user.Status = UserStatus.NEW;
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.UserType);

                user.Uic = await C3SDbContext.UicGateway.GetUicByIdAsync(context, user.UicId);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.UserType);
                user.Role = await C3SDbContext.RoleGateway.GetRoleByIdAsync(context, user.RoleId);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.UserType);
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    userCheck = await C3SDbContext.UserGateway.AddNewGovernmentUserAsync(context, user, modifier);
                }
                else
                {

                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(user.UserType);
                    ICollection<ModelState> ListValues = ModelState.Values;
                    List<object> Errors = new List<object>();
                    foreach (var item in ModelState.Values)
                    {
                        if (item.Errors.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            Errors.Add(item.Errors);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

user is an instance of GovernmentUser.cs, which inherits from User.cs.  UserType is a string property of User.  When I run this, all the instances of "System.Diagnostic.Debug.WriteLine(user.UserType);" return "G" in the Output window.  Heowever, the Errors list returns one item, telling me that UserType is null.

My questions are: what is going on here?  How can they both come to different results, when executed at the same type, and how can I get it so that ModelState.IsValid == true?

Comment: What kind of link is there between `ModelState` and `user`? Since you're inspecting `user.UserType`, how would `ModelState` know about `user`?

Comment: I think you'll need to show us the class definition of the User type.

Comment: Are you sure that the UserType field is actually to referring to one of the other objects sitting in DbContext that is getting validated?  i.e. Is it a different record than the user one you are working with that ends up with that error possibly to to an invalid Require on some other piece of data?

Comment: Are you saying `ModelState` is invalid because `UserType` is `null` - `ModelState` is set by the `DefaultModelBinder` based on the values in the request. Setting the value of a property after that does not change `ModelState`

Comment: @StephenMuecke, thank you.  I honestly didn't think of that.  I always assumed that ModelState.IsValid() would check the object at the moment IsValid() was called.  Are you saying it only checks when the enclosing controlling is called, and never again?

Comment: Yes. Its purpose is to check if the user has posted valid values. And you should not be using a data model in your view. Use a view model containing only the properties you need in the view. In the POST method, check if `ModelState` is invalid and if so, return the view so it can be corrected. Otherwise, map the view model to the data model, then update the data model and save.

Comment: Yeah, normally you don't want to expose the EF data model in your controller because it can cause security concerns.  You are better off creating your own View Model that has the required data on there and then you map it to your EF Model which does its own validation that would be different than the View Model validation.

Comment: not much choice on that.  I agree with you about viewmodels, but my boss says I can't make changes like that.

Comment: If you MUST expose the EF model directly here, just don't use ModelState.IsValid() at all.  It won't be helpful to you if you are setting properties after the fact.

Comment: Then find a new boss :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ModelState checks the data that was posted to you in MVC.  I don't know if this is in your controller or not, but if it is, then my guess is that the UserType wouldn't be on the original data that was posted.  I don't think you can use that check after setting it server-side.  It is a check on the data received from the client.  If UserType isn't required on the client side, just remove that rule from the Dto.  However, if you are uploading the actual Entity directly here and it is using the Required attribute that EF uses, then I would just save it like normal and let EF handle the valdiation instead of using ModelState.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that ModelState.IsValid() is not the final word on whether or not and EF can go ahead and declare it valid anyway?

Comment: Right.  ModelState checks what was posted.  EF doesn't use that.  It has its own Validator based on the DataAnnotation attributes.